# How to exit this while loop when the user presses enter

Tags: python, loops, exit

hi I am new to programming I just want to know how can I exit this program using just the enter? Can't use the if not due to the split.

```
while True:
    try:
        Student.id, Student.name, Student.degree = input("give id,name and degree or hit enter to exit").split(",")
```

Comment: Move the `split` call later, if input was provided; otherwise exit.

Answer (score 1):

If user hit enter, it sends an empty string. So you can check to see if it is empty string or not. using walrus operator:

```py
while inp := input("give id,name and degree or hit enter to exit"):
    Student.id, Student.name, Student.degree = inp.split(",")
```

without `:=`:

```py
while True:
    inp = input("give id,name and degree or hit enter to exit")
    if not inp:
        break
    Student.id, Student.name, Student.degree = inp.split(",")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `try`. The program will exit with an exception if the user just presses enter.

```py
while True:
    Student.id, Student.name, Student.degree = input("give id,name and degree or hit enter to exit").split(",")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you split this up into a number of steps to make it clearer and give you greater control over what is happening. For example:

```py
while True:
    values = input("give id,name and degree or hit enter to exit: ")

    if values:
        values = values.split(',')
        
        if len(values) == 3:
            id, name, degree = values
            print(f"ID: {id}  Name: {name}  Degree: {degree}")
        else:
            print("Please enter the correct number of arguments")
    else:
        break  # just enter was pressed
```

This approach has the benefit of being able to spot when the user has entered an incorrect number of arguments.